# Differents size of files between writing in Python and writing in C

Tags: python, c, binary, char, ascii

I'm wondering why when I'm writing the file in C its size is 131696B and when I'm writing the file in Python is divided by 2 (65848B) ? And so how to get the same size in C.

```
int str2bin(char *str) {

char *ptr = str;
int i;
char str1[] = "1";
char str0[] = "0";
FILE *fp = fopen("output_file.txt", "a");

for(; *ptr != 0; ++ptr)
{

    /* perform bitwise AND for every bit of the character */
    for(i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (*ptr & 1 << i){
             fwrite(str1, 1, sizeof(str1), fp);
         } else{
             fwrite(str0, 1, sizeof(str0), fp);
         }
    }
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

And the code to open the file I want to transform in binary:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long fsize = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
char *buffer = malloc(fsize + 1);

fread(buffer, 1, fsize, fp);

fclose(fp);
// printf("%s\n", buffer);
str2bin(buffer);
```

Thanks

Comment: Try printing out what `sizeof(str0)` is. Consider that maybe you just want a char, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
```

by doing --i instead of i-- you are writing only [0-6] of the byte.

You also are not writing in binary, you are writing in chars of 0 and 1, you would want

```
char str1[] = "1";
char str0[] = "0";
```

to be

```
 char str1 = 1;
 char str0 = 0;
```

Comment: It's working, thank you very much. But can you explain why is work though? because I don't understand why it's working without the [ ] ?